# How do I seal between the soffit and frieze board?

Tags: caulking, gap

I have a small gap between the wall and the porch roof, probably 1/8 inch or so. I was planning to use caulk to seal it up, but I'm not sure if that is the best product. I don't want to use the expanding gap filler (I've had bad experiences with it). Is silicone caulk appropriate, or should I use something else?

[image: picture of gap]
[image: another picture]

Comment: I would use quality exterior paintable caulk or clear silicone caulk. If you are concerned about that small crack, what do you intend to do about that big hole?

Comment: due to coloring matching issues I'd use roof patch.

Comment: I'm going to fill the hole as well. We have some ants, and I think this is where they are coming in from

Comment: I wouldn't use roof patch. The roof patch I've seen turns hard and tends to crack. Also a mess to work with.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, a caulk that matches the dark frieze board will probably be least conspicuous. You should be able to find a silicone or urethane that's very dark but not black. It might be called "dark walnut", or maybe "charcoal gray".

I'd avoid latex caulks as they don't bond particularly well and they shrink substantially.

If the cavity is deeper than 3/8" or so, pre-fill with foam rope caulk to act as a backer.

Answer (score 1):

Caulk. either clear or a color that matches one side of the gap